# How to log/audit windows user logins?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, login, windows-authentication

How can I capture Window's authenticated user's logging into the site? Forms users are easy enough to capture since they must go through the login form, but Window's users are either prompted with the Windows Authentication login, or they are logged in automatically if the browser is configured to pass their credentials to the site properly.

I'm using a custom login form at the moment.

SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms authentication and windows authentication can be captured by adding code to in the site master page.